# How to resolve website references with MSBuild without building website?

Tags: asp.net, msbuild, web

I have a solution that contains web-site and couple of dependent projects. I need to build this solution with MSBuild. The issue is that I need to build site itself only to resolve references and then just throw away results of build. I've taken a look on the solution .metaproj file, but it only contains target that allows me to build site. I'm using it, as it also resolves that references. It's not a critical issue, but in my case it takes two minutes of total fife to build that site itself.

Sure I can build dependent projects manually and then just copy build results... But every time new reference is added it will require modifications of build file.

So is there smart way doing this?

Comment: I'm struggling to see/figure out what you are trying to achieve. You can probably write a script that generates a new sln with all your references and then builds it. And then .. throws everything away..

Comment: I'm trying to accelerate my build, that includes, as a part, huge website with billion of references. I need that references built, but I don't need website built, as it takes bit of time (half of all the build time), and I don't need results of it, I only need references resolved. Solution you suppose will work, or (as I solved it), postbuild events to push-copy binaries into website for each dependency. But it still requires some manual interaction, into every dependency and that's bad. I'm looking for solution to have them compiled and resolved, but not site itself.

Comment: Can you put the other projects into a separate build - store the libraries in SVN and reference them from your website project?

Comment: I still don't understand how can this help build all website dependencies without some manual work like adding them to other solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just build it. Consider building it in parallel with /m, but other than writing your own half-compiler, you should just let the build system do this for you.